# Select HTML <input> elements with missing type attribute - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm working on a script, which should return all input elements with the type being set to *text*, *number*, *email* or *password*. I also want it to return all input fields with undefined type (missing attribute).

Is there an easy and fast way to do so?

This is my implementation so far:

```
inputFields = parentElem.find('input[type="text"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="password"]');
//fields with missing type attr aren't selected

inputFieldsWithoutType = parentElem.find('input');
for (var j = 0; j < inputFieldsWithoutType.length; j++) {
  if (inputFieldsWithoutType.eq(j).attr("type") === undefined || inputFieldsWithoutType.eq(j).attr("type") === null) {
    inputFields = inputFields.add(inputFieldsWithoutType.eq(j)); //add to other inputFields
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to select `input` elements without a `type` attribute is to combine the attribute selector `[type]` with the `:not()` pseudo class.

In doing so, we are essentially negating all `input` element that have a `type` attribute.

```
$('input:not([type])');
```

The above selector will select all elements without a `type` attribute, but if you want to select element without a `type` attribute *and* with an empty/undefined `type` attribute (such as `<input type="" />`), then you can use the `.filter()` method:

```
$inputFieldsWithoutType = $('input').filter(function () {
  return !this.getAttribute('type');
});
```

#### Example:

```js
$inputFieldsWithoutType = $('input:not([type])');
$inputFieldsWithoutTypeOrEmptyType = $('input').filter(function () {
  return !this.getAttribute('type');
});

snippet.log('Input elements without a type attribute: ' + $inputFieldsWithoutType.length);
snippet.log('Input elements without a type attribute or an empty type: ' + $inputFieldsWithoutTypeOrEmptyType.length);
```

```css
input{display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<input type="number" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="button" />
<input type=""/>
<input />
```